# Java OutOfMemoryError Exception

Tags: java

I'm confused on what OutOfMemoryError really is.

The question I have asks what the OutOfMemory exception signifies:

1. The process ran out of heap space
2. Process ran out of physical memory
3. Operating system ran out of virtual memory.

I have looked around online and there are many different answers for both number 1 and 3. I'm leaning towards answer 1 but I'm not so sure.

Comment: Did you read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html ?

Comment: From the [`OutOfMemoryError` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html): "*Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine cannot allocate an object because it is out of memory, and no more memory could be made available by the garbage collector. ...*" - In essence, the JVM was unable to allocate additional heap memory. This can either be becase it reached its heap limit or the OS was not able to provide more memory. --- A remark: this is an `Error`, not an `Exception`. It should never be caught.

Comment: There are several different scenarios that can cause an OutOfMemory error, including: a) running out of space in the Java heap, b) running out of space in the native heap, c) Running out of physical memory.  Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html) and [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sdk-java-technology/8?topic=usage-receiving-outofmemoryerror-exceptions) for more details.

Comment: @Cheshiremoe - no it doesn't.

Comment: @John S: please upvote one or both of the responses, and "Accept" one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: potentially all of them, more or less.

If you fill up the regular Java heap (and the GC is unable to reclaim enough space) you will get an `OutOfMemoryError`.  This is the most common case.

A process does not run out of physical memory *per se*.  Physical memory is the operating system's concern.  A process only sees virtual memory.

However, there are a few cases where you can get failures related to running out of physical RAM or virtual memory address space.  For example:

- When a 32-bit process fills all of the 32 bit address space (or at least all of it that can be mapped by the OS).
- When a process runs against virtual address space limits set from the outside; e.g. using `ulimit` on Linux.
- When the OS runs out of swap space for new virtual memory allocations.
- When swapping is disabled, and the OS runs out of physical RAM.

Each of these scenarios ... and others ... can trigger unusual `OutOfMemoryError`s at the point where the JVM requests a memory-related resource from the OS; e.g. to create a thread stack, allocate a direct buffer, grow the heap, and so on.

You can typically distinguish the different causes by looking carefully at the exception messages.  But doing it programmatically would be awkward.

And there is another scenario.  If the operating system has overcommitted RAM, and it notices that the virtual memory system is doing excessive paging / swapping I/O, the OSes "oomkiller" may decide to kill a process.  If the "victim" is a JVM, the Java application won't get an `OutOfMemoryError` at all, and it won't even get to execute shutdown hooks.  It will be "kill -9"'d.

Answer (score 0):

The most common case for `OutOfMemoryError` => It can happen when the heap is getting overrun and the (generally full `GC`) `GC` is running all the time to reclaim heap space but is unable make any meaningful progress. This is the most `common` use case as others have also pointed out.

*Process ran out of physical memory* => Modern OS do not deal with physical memory exclusively - they deal with virtual memory. When the process is reaching that threshold of "running" out of physical memory AND paging is going over a certain threshold (or swapping is disabled) then the `OS` would act and kill the process and/or other processes. It could also be that the JVM throws an `OutOfMemoryError` before that happens since the request to OS for more memory to grow the heap might fail. It might also be that the `JVM` throws not one but repeatedly many `OutOfMemoryErrors`. And then the OS takes over. See below for the `Linux OOM Killer`.

*OS ran out of virtual memory* => the JVM process can signal a `OutOfMemoryError` or the `OS` can kill it as specified above.

In addition to what is already answered, need to point out that in certain cases, the only evidence of the `JVM` process being killed is in the `OS` logs. You would not find any trace of the JVM throwing an `OutOfMemoryError` at all i your application log files (or in the JVM logs, traces etc.). The only evidence would be in the OS logs.

Note the JVM OOM error(`OutOfMemoryError`) is available on a best case basis. As there might be situations in which the JVM is unable to proceed further to even throw that error. It could also happen in case when the `OS` does a "`kill -9`" of processes that could include the `JVM`. For more info, read on the "[Linux OOM Killer](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/it-infrastructure/dev-oom-killer.html)" wherein the memory requirements exceed a certain threshold in the system.

In all, the issue of OS memory management is complex. Once a memory related error occurs then the specific reason will be detailed in either the JVM or application logs or in the OS logs.

Also note: if there is even one `OOM` error in the application or the `JVM` logs, you might find the application is still running. However, this does not mean that everything is recovered and is hunky dory. The `JVM` at this point could be in a corrupt state and it is best to kill and restart with appropriate testing.